# Twitter API v1.1 redirect to application does not work

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm a newbie with Twitter API and I'm trying to fetch the user timeline data in my application.

I have set the application settings and config.php file correctly, so the user logs in successfully and sees the "Redirecting back to your application" message, but after redirecting to http://MyDomainName.com/callback.php?oauth_token=someToken&oauth_verifier=someOtherToken the page does not show up in the browser and redirecting does not happen. Coming back to application page manually, the user is not logged in and must login again. Can anyone please help me with this?

Config.php

```
/**
 * @file
 * A single location to store configuration.
 */

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'ALPHA_NUMERIC_CONSUMER_KEY');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'ALPHA_NUMERIC_SECRET');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', "http://infosys.concordia.ca/MyApps/oauthProxy/callback.php");
define('OAUTH_COOKIE', 'my_twitter_app_oauth');
define('OAUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.concordia.ca'); //Example ".esri.com"
echo OAUTH_CALLBACK;

//REQUIRED - Encrypt your cookies
//http://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/oauth_diagram.png
//Create your own unique ENCRYPTION_KEY via Encrypt.get_RandomKey()
define('ENCRYPTION_KEY','MY_UNIQUE_ENCRYPTION_KEY'); 
//Create your own unique initialization vector via Encrypt.get_IV()
define('IV','MY_UNIQUE_IV');
define('DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE','America/Toronto');
```

Callabck.php

```
<?php

//Version 2.1 by AndyG 4/2013
//Changes
//- added OAuth Encrption

// Start session and load lib
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('twitteroauth/Encrypt.php');
require_once('config.php');

$content = null;    //for verification of credentials
$connection = null; //for getting access token

// check if cookie exists
if(isset($_COOKIE[OAUTH_COOKIE])){
    // redirect back to app
    if(isset($_SESSION['oauth_referrer'])){
        header('Location: '.$_SESSION['oauth_referrer']);
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    // if verifier set
    if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){

        //Best practice is to encrypt the cookies or not use cookies
        $key = base64_decode(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
        $iv = base64_decode(IV);
        $encrypt = new Encrypt($key,$iv,DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE);


        // Create TwitteroAuth object with app key/secret and token key/secret from default phase
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

        // get access token from twitter
        try{
            $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            header("HTTP/1.0 400 Error");
            echo "\n\nFailed retrieving access token: " .$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        //Add a credentials validation request. Added v2.0 by AndyG
        try{
            $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials','');
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
        // save token
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $access_token;
        // 1 year
        $cookie_life = time() + 31536000;

        if($content != null && $content->screen_name != ""){

            $token = base64_encode( $encrypt->encrypt($access_token['oauth_token']));
            $token_secret = base64_encode( $encrypt->encrypt($access_token['oauth_token_secret']));     

            //Update array with new encrypted values
            $access_token["oauth_token"] = $token;
            $access_token["oauth_token_secret"] = $token_secret;
            // echo "\n\n".var_dump($access_token); //for testing

            // set cookie
            setcookie(OAUTH_COOKIE, json_encode($access_token), $cookie_life, '/', OAUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN);
            //header('Location: ./callback.php');
            echo "<html><head><title>Valid Verification</title><body bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>";
            echo "<style type='text/css'>body{font-family:sans-serif;}</style>";
            echo "<table width='100%'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td>";
            echo "<a href='http://www.esri.com'><img src='edn.png' style='border-style:none' alt='ESRI Developer Network' /></a>";
            echo "</td></tr></table>";
            echo "<h2>Welcome:&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='".$content->profile_image_url."'></img>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@".$content->screen_name."</h2>";
            echo "<h4>You have successfully authenticated with Twitter. </h4>" ;
            echo "<h4>It is okay to close this page and return to the application.</h4>";
            echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
            echo "if(window.opener && window.opener.getTokens){";
            echo "window.opener.getTokens(\"".$_SESSION['oauth_token'].",".$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']."\");}";
            //You can also have the app automatically close the window via self.close, as shown below
            //echo "self.close();";
            echo "</script>";
            echo "</body></html>";
        }
        else{
            header("HTTP/1.0 400 Error");
            echo "\n\nFailed to validate credentials. ".$error;
            exit;
        }
        exit;
    }
    else{
       // redirect
        if(isset($_SESSION['oauth_referrer'])){
            header('Location: '.$_SESSION['oauth_referrer']);
        }
        else{
            header('Location: '.OAUTH_CALLBACK);
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad! The callback URL in application settings was not the same as the callback URL in config.php. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to see what you did wrong.

You have to either pass a fully qualified URL as `oauth_callback` when you fetch your initial request token, or hard-code a callback URL into your Twitter app [settings](https://dev.twitter.com/apps).

If you pass in the oauth_callback I believe you have to enter a dummy value in the settings or it won't work.

Comment: It seems that I didn't understand the oauth_callback URL. I'm using the code from [twitter API](https://github.com/Esri/flex-twittersearch-widget/tree/master/oauthproxy). In app settings, I've set the oauth_callback to callback.php on my server (which is [http://infosys.concordia.ca/MyApps/oauthproxy/callback.php](http://infosys.concordia.ca/MyApps/oauthproxy/callback.php)). I've edited the question and added the codes for config.php and callback.php.